# How to watch and set dynamically a variable?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, translation, watch

Hi it's my first post on StackOverflow.

I'm working on for translating dynamically a website. I'm using the package `vuejs-localization`.
How can I switch language directly?

I'm working with the latest version of VueJS and Laravel.

This is my code on my language selector:

```
export default {
  name: "LanguageDropDown",
  data() {
    return {
      languages: [
        {
          lang: "fr",
          text: "Français",
          icon: "fr",
        },
        {
          lang: "gb",
          text: "English",
          icon: "gb",
        },
        {
          lang: "us",
          text: "US",
          icon: "us"
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    getCurrentLang: function() {      
      return this.$lang.getLang();
    },
  },
  methods: {
    setLanguage(lang) {
      this.$root.$emit("setLang", lang);
    },
    setLang(lang, index) {
      this.$root.$emit("setLang", this.languages[index].languages[lang], index);
    },
  },
};
```

And this is what is in my App.js :

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  data() {
    return {
      lang: 'fr'
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.$lang.setLang( this.lang ); 
  },
  mounted() {
    let _this = this;
    this.$root.$on( 'setLang', function( lang ){      
      _this.lang =  lang ; 
      console.log(_this.lang);
    });
  },
  watch: {
    lang :{
      handler(val){
        this.lang = val;
        console.log('changed to :' + this.lang);
      },
    },
  },
})
```

I expect a translation by changing the variable 'fr' to 'us' or 'gb' but the log says that the lang is switching but nothing happened ...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't understand why you are using a watch on lang data instead of setting the valur directly inside your `.on` event

Comment: I was accustomed to do like this so it was the only way i wanted to fix it

Answer (score 0):

To make language changes, you need to call `this.$lang.setLang`. You can do it in watch

```
watch: {
    lang :{
      handler(val){
        this.lang = val;
        this.$lang.setLang(val)
        console.log('changed to :' + this.lang);
      },
    },
  },
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, the translation is only done when I go on an other page but at least it work.
If you have an idea for that, you're welcome.

Thanks for your attention !